# describe().to_csv is missing the description column in the csv file

Tags: python, pandas, csv, describe

When I use

```
df.describe().to_csv("data.csv", index=False)
```

I get the results for each column but the first column with the descriptions of each row is missing.

So I can't see in the csv which value describes what.

```
count
mean
std
...
```

is missing.

How can I get that column as the first column in my csv export like I see it when using

```
print(df.describe())
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are excluding the index:

```
df.describe().to_csv("data.csv", index=False)
```

The label on each row in the `describe()` output is an index value:

```
>>> df.describe().index
Index(['count', 'mean', 'std', 'min', '25%', '50%', '75%', 'max'], dtype='object')
```

You want to *include* the index, so set `index=True`. That's the default, so you can also just use `df.describe().to_csv("data.csv")`.